# Constrained optimisation of function with nonzero gradient

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, constraints

Suppose a continuous function $f(x,y,z):\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is such that $\nabla f(x,y,z)\neq\mathbf{0}$ for every $(x,y,z)\in [0,1]^3$. A property of the gradient is that it is zero at stationary points. Thus one can say that there is no stationary point in the interior of the cube. The cube is compact, so $f$ must have minimum and maximum on it. Hence these must be on the boundary of the cube. Suppose the restrictions of $f$ on each face of the cube share the same property, that is $\nabla_{x,y}f(x,y,0)\neq \mathbf{0}$ etc. I believe the reasoning then iterates and one can conclude that the maximum and minimum must occur on the edges of the cube. For a function having such property, constrained maximisation and minimisation is thus reduced to the standard univariate study of the maxima and minima of the restrictions of $f$ on the edges of the cube. Is there anything wrong with this reasoning? Thanks for any opinion you can share.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: thank you for confirming!

Comment: The function $f(x,y,z)=\|(x,y,z)-(-0.5,0.5,0.5)\|^2$ achieves minimum at $(0,0.5,0.5)$ over $[0,1]^{3}$ and it does not have vanishing derivatives over the cube  $[0,1]^3$ . Something is wrong in your argument. Can you find where?

Comment: Sorry but I do not see a contradiction here. Your function does not have vanishing gradient in the interior of the cube, so the extremum might be on any of the faces of the cube. On the face having $x=0$ the gradient $\nabla_{y,z}f(0,y,z)$ does vanish at $y=z=.5$ so the fact that the extremum happens to be there is not a contradiction at all. It would be a contradiction if it could not vanish, and yet the extremum was there.